# How to access and retrive Sets, Maps, and others variables from an FXMLController using Java 8

Tags: parsing, methods, constructor, java-8, javafx-8

```
Summary:
```

I am using JavaFX with FXML to load up a text file from the FXMLParseMeController.java , then perform few parses and edits via another class called ReadFile.java. So, I load up the text file --> pass it to another class -->For each complete line that gets edited I pass it to a contructor to do some pattern match then assign the found matches to variables, HashMap or sets.   My missing link is how to access the parsed and the new assigned values from my FXML..Controller class?

```
My Setup:
```

After the controller load up the stage and I select the file, I pass the "filepath" to ReadFile class.  and for testing, I printout all the new modified lines after parse via the console.

FXMLParseMeController.java

```
ReadFile file = new ReadFile(filePath);
List<String> aryLines  = file.OpenFile(); 
aryLines.forEach(System.out::println);
```

ReadFile.java

```
public class ReadFile {
private String path;
   ReadFile(String filePath) {
    path = filePath;
}
public List<String> OpenFile() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        String line;
        StringBuilder concatenatedLine = new StringBuilder();
        List<String> formattedStrings = new ArrayList<>();

       //few While loops and if Statements, then pass:  
       testScan(concatenatedLine);
    }

private void testScan(StringBuilder concatenatedLine) {
   if (..) {
       String str1 = "some value";
   }else if (...){
       Set<String> str2 = new TreeSet<String>();
       str2.add("value");
   }
```

Now, how can I retrieve or display  String str1 and Set str2 from FXMLParseMeController.java?

Comment: You must be more accurate in your description of a problem. You have List<String> returned from ReadFile (not str1 or str2), so why don't you show this list in ListView (List from javafx)?

Comment: List<String> contains all the lines of the file I loaded. which I only have  there just for testing. but in reality as stated above, I feed every line to testScan() and assign values based on pattern match.

Comment: So, you want to show in gui str1 and str2, which are fields of ReadFile.class?